# setFullScreenIntent not working when screen is locked in android 10

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-alarms, android-10.0, android-fullscreen

I am trying to set a **fullScreentIntent** using NotificationCompat in android 10 when the alarm goes on but the fullScreenIntent is not showing even when the alarm goes on.

I added **USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT** in manifest file. I tried acquiring partial wake lock, disabling keyguard but still, the fullscreen intent is not working.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
```

**AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "AlarmBroadcastReceiver";
    public static final String STOP_CHANNEL_ID = "Location Alert";
    public static final int ALARM_NOTIFICATION_ID = 2;

    public static MediaPlayer mp;
    public static Vibrator vibrator;

    private boolean isVibrationEnabled = false;
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        showStopNotification(context);

        long[] mVibratePattern = new long[]{0, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400};
        final int[] mAmplitudes = new int[]{0, 128, 0, 128, 0, 128, 0, 128};

        isVibrationEnabled = intent.getExtras().getBoolean(LocationAlertService.IS_VIBRATE);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ring1);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();

        if(isVibrationEnabled) {
            vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(mVibratePattern, mAmplitudes, 0));
            } else {
                //deprecated in API 26
                vibrator.vibrate(mVibratePattern, 3);
            }
        }

    }

    public void showStopNotification(Context context) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            NotificationChannel stopServiceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    STOP_CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Location Alert Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(stopServiceChannel);

            Intent wakeupIntent = new Intent(context, WakeUpActivity.class);
            wakeupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            PendingIntent wakeupPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, wakeupIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            wakeupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            PendingIntent mainPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
            keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
                    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                    | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,
                    "MyApp::" + TAG);
            wakeLock.acquire(10000);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, STOP_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.location_alerter)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getText(R.string.stop_location_alert))
                    .setContentText(context.getResources().getText(R.string.click_to_stop_activity))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setFullScreenIntent(wakeupPendingIntent, true);

            Notification alarmNotification = notificationBuilder.build();

            notificationManager.notify(0, alarmNotification);
            wakeLock.release();
        }
        else {
            Intent wakeIntent = new Intent(context, WakeUpActivity.class);
            wakeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(wakeIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

On **onReceive()** I am calling **showStopNotification()** which checks if the device runs on android 10 or not. If it runs on android 10 I am trying to acquire wakelock and launch the activity using **NotificationCompat.builder's setFullScreenIntent().** I even set the notification priority as high.

I don't know why the fullScreenIntent is not shown after the alarm goes on. The sound and vibration are working but there is no UI to stop the alarm. Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: I do have the same problem. Do you found any solution for this?

Comment: No, I did a workaround. When the alarm is triggered I am popping a notification and by clicking that the user can dismiss the alarm. Let me know if you find any other solutions @Gatschet

Comment: Could you share your workaround with me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve you notification channel (STOP_CHANNEL_ID) priority to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding permission `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` as well as `USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT` to your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Do not set Id to notify as 0

> notificationManager.notify(0, alarmNotification);